# Why does $\frac{n!n^x}{(x+1)_n}=\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^x\prod_{j=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{x}{j}\right)^{-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{j}\right)^x$

Tags: special-functions

Why does $$\frac{n!n^x}{(x+1)_n}=\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^x\prod_{j=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{x}{j}\right)^{-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{j}\right)^x$$ where the subscript n is the rising factorial in the left denominator

my attempt:
the index n in the product indicates the indicates the term $\left(1+\frac{x}{j}\right)^{-1}$ may be some series of infinite geometric sums from the rising factorial but how?
This is page 2 in Andrews, Askey, Roy Special Functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\prod_{j=1}^n\left(\frac{j+1}j\right)^x$$ telescopes and equals $(n+1)^x$. Multiplying
by
$$\left(\frac n{n+1}\right)^x$$
gives $n^x$.
$$\prod_{j=1}^n\left(1+\frac xj\right)^{-1}=\frac{n!}{(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+n)}
=\frac{n!}{(x+1)^{(n)}}$$
etc. (I prefer $x^{(n)}$ and $x_{(n)}$ for the rising and falling factorials resp.)